# Sending emails from a (distributable) desktop application

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

The problem I'm facing is I need my application to send emails to addresses that users of the application provide, and I'm not allowed to hardcode the smtp details (port, host, user etc) as each user of the application needs to provide their own. I just tried doing this with gmail and it failed because I opted in for a 2-Step verification (it requires an app specific password if 2-step verification is set up) and I'm afraid a few of the users will face the same problem. What's the simplest way to send an email provided that you don't have the smtp details at compile time and you want to send from a variety of smtp hosts?

Comment: Either save the details for each user in DB or ask them to provide while sending emails - mark them mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "simple" way.  You have to ask the user for the details of their SMTP server.